# CouchDB replies with 404 Object not found when HTTP POST is used

Tags: couchdb

I have recently upgraded CouchDB form 1.01 to 1.5.0 and I am getting the following error. Every time I try to create a new document using HTTP POST (as I did previously using the jQuery library, that is, saveDoc()) I am getting this response

> 404 Object not found
>   {"error":"not_found","reason":"missing"}

I have no idea of why this is happening since the only thing I did was to upgrade.

I have check that everything works fine if I try to modify an existing document using PUT (same function, `saveDoc()`).

Any direction, please?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: According to [the docs](http://couchdb.readthedocs.org/en/latest/api/database/common.html#post--db), it should return 404 if the db is not found. Did you check the log? Is there a typo in the db name?

Comment: @Simon, I checked the log and this is what I found: `[Wed, 24 Sep 2014 15:35:46 GMT] [info] [<0.9229.3>] 192.168.1.100 - - POST /interlearning/_design/interlearning/_rewrite/interlearning 404` It seems that it is rewriting the URL, but only when POST is used, because it is not rewritten when a PUT is used. I check all the rewrite rules and there is no distinction between methods.

Comment: Strange, [the doc](http://couchdb.readthedocs.org/en/latest/api/ddoc/rewrites.html) says: “method is equal to "*" by default, and will match any HTTP method”. In your case the 404 means that no rewrite rule matched.

Comment: **SOLVED**: I use rewrite rules in my application. It is based on Couchapp and I need them in order to deal with some redirections and to avoid easy access to some documents. It seems that newer versions of CouchDB are managing rewrite rules in a different way. It was rewriting the URL with some kind of "default" or "most approximate" rule, becase it was not a specific rewrite rule for that URL (in older versions simply no rewrite rule was applied). Now I had to include an explicit rewrite rule for that case.

Comment: Great! Please write the solution in an answer and accept it instead of writing it in the body of the question. That's best practice on SO.

Comment: This is the rule: {
       "to": "../../*",
       "from": "/interlearning/*"
   },